# open old swf files in browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, flash

I have some old swf (shockwave flash) files with actionscript 3 in them. I know of websites that also host other files such as games.
I know flash was discontinued a year or two back, but I have Ruffle extension on my chrome browser, and when loading a website this manages to run the embedded flash files fine. However if I attempt to open .swf files from my local disk in the browser, it simply tries to 'download' them rather than running.

How do I overcome this and run the files?

Answer (score 0):

It's next to impossible nowadays to get a browser to play SWF files.

I suggest to use the
[VLC player](https://www.videolan.org/).

Comment: VLC works well on *some* SWF files, and the free VSDC converter, https://www.videosoftdev.com/, can change it to a safer format. SWF has been deprecated for years for **security**, since it can be a vehicle for **malware**: https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/11/malicious-injector-in-swf-adobe-flash-file.html You might be able to get an ancient, unsafe browser to run in a VM, but **why** would you want that?